# Launch Map App when user double clicks a text address in a application

Tags: java, android, dictionary

Is it possible to launch Androids Map App when the user double clicks on an address in a text view of another application?

Similar to when you click on a group of numbers Android will open the phone dialer with the number in the phone number text box.

Is it possible this functionality depends on the version of Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uri geoUri = Uri.parse("address here");
Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
startActivity(mapCall);

Comment: the address string should be sometihng like "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;

Comment: So if I have a DB with thousands of addresses (no lat and long's) Maybe I could use a third party and pass the address to it and get the lat and long back, and then use the Uri. Does that sound like a solid process? Thanks for you help so far! +1

Comment: You can also launch the maps app with a standard address. The string you input would be Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Brooklyn,NY") . I think you might have to do a url encode if the address has spaces.

Comment: I see, so its like the google map api you would use on a website. Thought it was a different animal all together. Thanks again.